# Bootstrap 4 - form row with select input not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm following along with [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-grid), and attempting to implement a row of form inputs for a registration form I'm building.  Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/register/" class="fos_user_registration_register">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_name" class="required">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_name" name="fos_user_registration_form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line1" name="fos_user_registration_form[line1]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line2">Address Line 2 (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line2" name="fos_user_registration_form[line2]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                <select id="fos_user_registration_form_state" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phone">Phone (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_phone" name="fos_user_registration_form[phone]" />
        </div>

        <small>We only ship within the US</small>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Register account</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="knrAUCbJNdBKVtkqR57qEzOAExZaqWmleKA4nRBiKeg" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which results in:

[image]

No matter what column width I give the three elements in the row, they simply don't fit neatly within the row.  I'm guessing part of the problem is the state dropdown... it's width doesn't shrink as much as I'd like.  But even if I set the city and zipcode widths narrower, so the total is less than 12 columns wide, the alignment is still borked in a similar way as the screenshot.

One important thing to note - I can't really change the wrapper `div`'s classes/attributes.  This is a Symfony project, so that wrapper element is the base for all my forms.  The others look right, so I really don't want to mess with it simply for this outlier.

Comment: in your first <div class=" ... py-4  ..." > is that a custom class, or a misspell class of pt-4?.

Comment: Definitely post the rest of the real code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @Yoarthur - py-4 is valid. It's the vertical padding of the element.

Comment: I've edited my question so it has the rendered code rather than what's in my Twig template

Comment: Looking at it with my browser's development tools, it looks like, for whatever reason, the zipcode input isn't being resized according to the column specification.  The form group and label are the right sizes, but the input is wider than it should be.

Comment: works fine inn codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oJbERM, can you provide any additional css that you are using which seems to be causing that issue

Comment: @MajorProductions did you see the solution below? Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy fix, the three form elements in the row with the select are missing the class `form-control`

Add that and it will render correctly

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/register/" class="fos_user_registration_register">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_name" class="required">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_name" name="fos_user_registration_form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line1" name="fos_user_registration_form[line1]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line2">Address Line 2 (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line2" name="fos_user_registration_form[line2]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                <select id="fos_user_registration_form_state" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]" class="form-control"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phone">Phone (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_phone" name="fos_user_registration_form[phone]" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <small>We only ship within the US</small>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Register account</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="knrAUCbJNdBKVtkqR57qEzOAExZaqWmleKA4nRBiKeg" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also added it to your phone number field for consistency.

See demo
https://codepen.io/twickstrom/pen/wRMmaa

Answer (score 1):

As all the other answers state, using `form-control` will help. But you still may have some overlap at smaller screen widths.

Instead of using `col-md-4`, use `col-md` and/or `col-md-auto` to better fit the inputs.

- `col*` will grow to fill the width.
- `col-*-auto` will shrink-to-fit the width of its content.

  ```
    <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md">
                  <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                  <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="form-control" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-auto">
                  <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                  <select id="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="form-control" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]">
                      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                      ...
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md">
                  <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                  <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="form-control" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required">
              </div>
    </div>
  ```

https://www.codeply.com/go/oCoGMyfmXv

***Also,*** you could use `px-0` on the state select col to make more room for it to fit, and shrink the space between the inputs.

***Another option*** is to used a defined width on *one* of the columns, such as `col-md-3` on the select. Combine this with `col-md` and the select with shrink to 25% of the row width, and the other 2 cols with fill the remaining width.

```
   <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md">
                    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="form-control" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                    <select id="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="form-control" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        ...
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md">
                    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="form-control" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required">
                </div>
    </div>
```

[Demo of both options](https://www.codeply.com/go/oCoGMyfmXv)

Answer (score 0):

Add "`w-100`" class on `input` and `select` tags inside form-group element. It will fix your issue

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
    <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="w-100" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required" />
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/register/" class="fos_user_registration_register">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fos_user_registration_form_name" class="required">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_name" name="fos_user_registration_form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
          <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line1" name="fos_user_registration_form[line1]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line2">Address Line 2 (optional)</label>
          <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line2" name="fos_user_registration_form[line2]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="w-100" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
            <select id="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="w-100" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
            <input class="w-100" type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phone">Phone (optional)</label>
          <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_phone" name="fos_user_registration_form[phone]" />
        </div>

        <small>We only ship within the US</small>

        <div>
          <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Register account</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="knrAUCbJNdBKVtkqR57qEzOAExZaqWmleKA4nRBiKeg" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the hole form is coming in col-lg-4 and three column is not fitting in col-lg-4

please use below div

```
<div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-3 col-md-5 col-lg-7 justify-content-center align-items-center">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `class="form-control"` in input control of City, Zipcode and State.

Look at below HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/register/" class="fos_user_registration_register">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_name" class="required">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_name" name="fos_user_registration_form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line1" name="fos_user_registration_form[line1]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line2">Address Line 2 (optional)</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line2" name="fos_user_registration_form[line2]" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                    <select id="fos_user_registration_form_state" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phone">Phone (optional)</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_phone" name="fos_user_registration_form[phone]" />
            </div>

            <small>We only ship within the US</small>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Register account</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="knrAUCbJNdBKVtkqR57qEzOAExZaqWmleKA4nRBiKeg" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it will looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="form-control"`. Codepen: https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/maVjwb

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/register/" class="fos_user_registration_register">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_name" class="required">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_name" name="fos_user_registration_form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line1" name="fos_user_registration_form[line1]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line2">Address Line 2 (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line2" name="fos_user_registration_form[line2]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="fos_user_registration_form_state" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phone">Phone (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_phone" name="fos_user_registration_form[phone]" />
        </div>

        <small>We only ship within the US</small>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Register account</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="knrAUCbJNdBKVtkqR57qEzOAExZaqWmleKA4nRBiKeg" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React, for me it was react-bootstrap Form.Control being 10px to the right of Form.Select

To fix I just made marginLeft:0px for Form.Control

```js
<>
<Form.Group className="mb-3" >
  <Form.Label>{object.Header}</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control style={{marginLeft:'0px'}} placeholder={`Enter a ${object.Header}`} />
</Form.Group>
</>
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to add class "form-control" in city's input, state's select box and zip's input  like [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-grid).

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="my-5 py-4 offset-md-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/register/" class="fos_user_registration_register">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_name" class="required">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_name" name="fos_user_registration_form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line1" name="fos_user_registration_form[line1]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_line2">Address Line 2 (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_line2" name="fos_user_registration_form[line2]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_city" class="required">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" class="form-control" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_state" class="required">State</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="fos_user_registration_form_state" name="fos_user_registration_form[state]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" class="required">Zipcode</label>
                <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" required="required" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fos_user_registration_form_phone">Phone (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_phone" name="fos_user_registration_form[phone]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <small>We only ship within the US</small>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Register account</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="knrAUCbJNdBKVtkqR57qEzOAExZaqWmleKA4nRBiKeg" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```